# Cancelling an iPhone calendar event from an ics email attachment

Tags: iphone, icalendar

I'm creating an email that contains a VCalendar event in it's body. This displays as an ics attachment in the email of my iPhone 4 (IOS v5.1.1 9B206).
I can open this attachment and add the event to my iPhone calendar by clicking the "Add to Calendar" button.

Now, I'm trying to cancel events the same way.

I'm generating the same UID as the original event (based on the date and time of the event), setting Method to CANCEL and Status to CANCELLED (as recommended), however, although I can see the ics attachment in the email, I cannot open the attachment on my iPhone.

ics being sent:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//mycompany.com//test
METHOD:CANCEL
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PRIVATE
UID:20120924T090000
DTSTAMP:20120923T151052
DTSTART:20120924T090000
DTEND:20120924T130000
LOCATION:Normal
DESCRIPTION:Always a description
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:Cancelling
ORGANIZER;CN="Test":mailto:donotreply@test.com
ATTENDEE;CN="Mr Smith":mailto:mr.smith@test.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**UPDATE:**

This actually works on my 1st generation iPad (IOS 5.1.1 9B206), so I'm now thinking it's because my iPhone doesn't have my exchange calendar.

**UPDATE 2:**

I've eventually managed to get my Exchange calendar syncing to my iPhone by re-entering the name of the email server, this re-validated/refreshed the details and now all my Outlook appointments sync.

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding and cancelling an appointment on iPhone from an ics email attachment both work as long as everything is set up correctly.

You can add an appointment to any calendar (I was adding them to my local calendar).

You cannot cancel an appointment from a local calendar, I needed to synch my Exchange calendar to my iPhone to allow me to cancel events that I'd added.